# axios is not getting any data from an api

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, axios

my axios function is not returning any json data from an api.

Here is the request function

```js
  const getCoins = async () => {
      try {
          return await (await axios.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets'));
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  }
```

I call this function on my index route

```js
  app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
      res.render('index', {title:'Index',data:getCoins});
      console.log(getCoins);
  });
```

The console.log does not log any data, only the entire function like so:

```js
async () => {
      try {
          return await JSON.stringify(axios.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets')); 
      } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
      }
  }
```

Meaning I can't loop through it on my index page

```js
   <tr>
   <% for( let index = 0; index < data.length; index++ ) { %>
    <td>data[i].id</td>
    <td>data[i].rank</td>
    <td>data[i].symbol</td>
    <td>data[i].priceUsd</td>
    <td>data[i].changePercent24Hr</td>
   <% } %>
   </tr>
```

The data I am expecting to be returned is this

```json
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "bitcoin",
      "rank": "1",
      "symbol": "BTC",
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "supply": "17193925.0000000000000000",
      "maxSupply": "21000000.0000000000000000",
      "marketCapUsd": "119150835874.4699281625807300",
      "volumeUsd24Hr": "2927959461.1750323310959460",
      "priceUsd": "6929.8217756835584756",
      "changePercent24Hr": "-0.8101417214350335",
      "vwap24Hr": "7175.0663247679233209"
    },
],
```

Comment: `res.render('index', {title:'Index', ...(await getCoins()).data});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors

1. Remove one await from getCoins

```
const getCoins = async () => {
    try {
        return await axios.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets'));
    } catch (error) {
        return error
    }
}
```

2. you must wait to get the data from an async function, so add await before getCoins. Also add `()` to call a function

```
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {title:'Index',data:getCoins});
    console.log(await getCoins());
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not how you use async/await. You must await the result, put it into a variable, then use it. Try that :

```
 const getCoins = async () => {
  try {
      const result = await axios.get('https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets');
      console.log(result);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }
```

}

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple tastes, but i do it like this:

```
app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let response = await getCoins();
    console.log("response", response.data);
    res.render("index.html"); // also attach data to handle by view engine, ...
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    // handle all errors here based on which type or which function returns error
    /// res.render() error page or suitable http status, ...
  }
});

let getCoins = () => axios.get("https://api.coincap.io/v2/assets");
```

Answer (score -1):

You must add parentheses to print the output of a function

`console.log(getCoins())`